# Regex inserting variable with non-escaped \ characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following that attempts to parse the output from Unrar extracting a .rar. I have the following line that is throwing an error: *too short escape sequence*. This is caused by the variable *extractLocation* being equal to a filepath with \ characters (ex. I:\Rar\Backups\) that aren't escaped. Is there a way to reference the literal string interpretation of this variable in my regex? If not, what other approaches can I take to solving this problem?

```
stdoutArr = stdout.split("\n")

stdoutArr.each do |line|
#line below is throwing the error   
if line.match(/((?<=(Extracting  #{extractLocation})).*.bak)/)
        extractedFile = line[(/((?<=(Extracting  #{extractLocation})).*.bak)/)]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
regexp = /((?<=(Extracting  #{Regexp.escape(extractLocation)})).*.bak)/
```

How does this work?

- `Regexp.escape(...)` escapes all special characters